# Cannot invoke vararg methods in scala

Tags: scala, reflection, methods, invoke, variadic-functions

I'm creating a combinator parser in scala. The parse tree consists of Actions I need to visit when evaluating the parsed expression. One of these actions (the Function) will call a method on another object by reflection, but this fails when that is a vararg-method.

This is the code demonstrating the problem:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class M {
  def e: Double = { Math.E }
  def add(x: Double, y: Double): Double = { x + y }
  def sin(x: Double): Double = { Math.sin(x * Math.PI / 180) }
  def max(args: Double*): Double = { args.max }
}

sealed trait Action { def visit: Double }
case class Number(value: Double) extends Action { def visit: Double = value }
case class Function(Name: String, Args: Action*) extends Action {
  def visit: Double = {
    typeOf[M].member(Name: TermName) match {
      case NoSymbol     => throw new Error(s"Unknown function '$Name'")
      case func: Symbol => runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).reflect(new M).reflectMethod(func.asMethod)(
        (for { arg <- Args } yield arg.visit).toList: _*).asInstanceOf[Double]
    }
  }
}

object Parser {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Prints 2.718281828459045
    println(Function("e").visit)

    // Prints 7.0
    println(Function("add", Number(3), Number(4)).visit)

    // Prints 1.2246467991473532E-16
    println(Function("sin", Number(180)).visit)

    // Throws IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    println(Function("max", Number(1), Number(2.5), Number(50), Number(-3)).visit)
  }
}
```

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Oops, missed a bit of the reflect API. The `func` is a `MethodSymbol` which has the `isVarargs` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a copy&paste solution, but I am sure you get the idea:

```
case class VarArgsFunction(Name: String, Args: Action*) extends Action {
  def visit: Double = {
    typeOf[M].member(Name: TermName) match {
      case NoSymbol     => throw new Error(s"Unknown function '$Name'")
      case func: Symbol => {
        runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).reflect(new M).reflectMethod(func.asMethod)(
          (for { arg <- Args } yield arg.visit).toList).asInstanceOf[Double]
      }
    }
  }
}

object Parser {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    // Prints 2.718281828459045
    println(Function("e").visit)

    // Prints 7.0
    println(Function("add", Number(3), Number(4)).visit)

    // Prints 1.2246467991473532E-16
    println(Function("sin", Number(180)).visit)

    // Throws IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    println(VarArgsFunction("max", Number(1), Number(2.5), Number(50), Number(-3)).visit)
  }
}
```

Comment: I know your solution works for calls to vararg-methods, however during parsing (and visiting) I cannot know whether the method being called is a vararg-method or not.